# Help with differential equation $y=2y'x + \frac {1}{y'}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please do it :
$y=2y'x + \frac {1}{y'}$
I know that this have no solution, but i have no idea to prove this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So

y'=p

$p\;dx=2p\;dx +2x\;dp- \frac{dp}{p^2}$

or

$\frac{dx}{dp}= -\frac 2p x + \frac {1}{p^3}$

$x=\frac{1}{p^2}C+\frac{\ln p}{p^2}$

$y=\frac 2p C+\frac 1p [2\ln p +1]$

now you must check if there are peculiar solutions

$2p=p$

There is only one solution p=0, but $p\neq0$ because y' is in denominator, so $y=2y'x$ + $\frac {1}{y'}$ have not solution